# Do American users also confuse the day and the month in dates like 01/02/2013

Tags: dates, formatting

Almost everywhere outside the United States, when short dates, e.g. 01/02/2013, are shown on computer screens, the user can't be sure whether **the first two digits represent the day or the month**. Is it January second or February first?

This is a big problem for people outside the United States, as they encounter both formats regularly, and can't know if the system has adapted to their locale, or has stuck with the American format. But I assume American users see mostly the American format (because many, if not most, information systems are built by or for Americans). What I'm curious about is **whether American users also are confused in this scenario**?

If you can point to some evidence or research, great. If not, I'll settle for your knowledgeable experience.

Note: I'm not asking for the wonderful solution of naming the month, e.g. May 21, 2013. I'm asking about the cases where a short date format has to be used.

Comment: I always fail when going into a ps3 game site that asks age confirmation and there's input fields defaulted like "01/01/2013", even if the inputs are dropdowns, I first try typing 14 into the first, and then I notice that the dropdown has max value of 12, so then I type the 14 into the second field and put the month in the first one. I'm from Finland and we have dd.mm.yyyy.

Comment: A date presented in a way that has the possibility of being ambiguous is always going to get confused when there is no key letting them know what the format is.  This is pure logic.

Comment: SamuelM and JohnGB, we are Europeans, and we encounter both formats. Of course we are getting confused. But in the States, people might always assume the format is the American one. I want to know if they also confuse the day and the month.

Comment: I am an American and I get confused, never realized the date formats were American VS the rest of world. I always just assumed some people liked the month first and others the day first.

Comment: You could always pick something [weirder](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/81539/1696).

Comment: No, I'd say almost everywhere outside USA people would be sure that the 01/02/2013 is 1st February, since middle indian format would seem so absurd to them that they wouldn't even think someone may use it. I have noticed that on some forums the posts are not sorted correctly by dates, and some posts are in future, but I haven't even thought that month could be written first! Imagine the time 44:12:21 and guess what time it is :D:D

Comment: [Relavant XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: "The rest of the world" does not use DMY date order.  East Asians use YMD (as does ISO 8601).

Comment: As a Canadian, we technically subscribe to the mm/dd/yyyy format like Americans, but I personally hate it and find it a horrible system for the reasons already stated. Fwiw in case it hasn't been mentioned, the reason it is like this at all is due to how we (North) Americans speak the date conversationally, e.g. "February 2nd, 2013". I prefer yyyy-mm-dd, or (less ideally) dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: I recently noticed that the only countries with date formats that do as @devios and I prefer are South Africa and its neighbors (YYYY/MM/DD) and Albania (YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: To answer your actual question, I always have to think about **9/11** to remember which order they come in, and I have lived in the US all my life. I have never heard of anyone calling it 11/9 or 11th September or anything else. I assume that "9/11" is recognized around the world, alongside that other "day that will live in infamy." I assume most people recognize August 6th as well, which is probably more important than any other date in history (and hopefully all of the future).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I don't have a pointer to published research - but in my experience US folk will  always assume the US MM/DD/YYYY format unless they are knowingly using an non-US site, and are already aware of the potential differences.

If you have to use numbers only then the format that causes least confusion across cultures in my experience is YYYY-MM-DD since it differs from both "defaults" and doesn't suffer from any assumptions.

That said using an abbreviated three letter month name is only one extra character - the size argument for using numbers is usually bogus.

Comment: +1 In my opinion, it's also more natural to use a month name (or abbreviation). People rarely talk about being in the '5th month' rather than 'May'.

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD also of course sorts chronologically using an alphabetical sort, which may or may not be useful

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is actually the ISO standard. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Obligatory https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: @Brendon - actually, Japanese uses numbered months, instead of naming them.

Comment: @SteveBennett: Three-letter abbreviated English names are the probably the most readable form for English speakers; perhaps less so for those in other cultures.  I like YYYY-MM-DD because it's sortable, culture-agnostic, and essentially unambiguous.

Comment: Three letter month names are nice by I recently noticed  that not every language has month name abbreviations with 3 letters. Some languages don't even have month abbreviations and when an abbreviation is requested from the date formatter, a number (or ordinal number) is used instead.

Comment: Note that YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ascends as expected.

Comment: I'm still encountering (and using) YYMMDD in some circumstances as it's more compact - this is very common in e.g. service histories of cars and other minor logs/reports. But swapping the month and day with each other makes no sence - the units are ordered by size for a reason. Americans are simply stupid. :-)

Comment: @Brendon. I tend to give my birthday as "the xth of the yth" in speech (i.e., the third of the ninth; the first of the fourth; the second of the fifth).

Comment: @TRiG I am sure that the BORG find you adorable.

Answer (score 13):

Please see ISO 8601
(eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

First, this is simply the largest to the smallest unit.  No other argument--no matter how tightly held--can seem to overcome this logic.

The 4-digit year removes any confusion as to what the other numbers represent--even when the hyphens are left out.  (Use of a 2-digit year--in any order--cannot always establish anything.)

I discovered this dating schema decades ago looking at a Star Trek calendar and saw that stardates were yyyymm.dd  (Note:  I was looking at calendars--not Star Trek stuff.)

I am an American with a mild dyslexia.  I saw (or perceived) just enough dates that were written "backwards" that I could and can never remember which order we are expected to presume they mean if the days (or years) are also 1-12.  (I also eschew the " / " as these make the date look confusing.)

I use year-month-date both with and increasingly with out hyphens or spaces; and day, year month date where the day and the month are spelled out.  This is by my choice--the ISO 8601 just gives me a fallback argument--in case I ever need one.

NOTE:  Some software programs might use, eg, "mm" for minutes, "MM" for month in numbers, and "MMMM" for the month spelled out; "hh" might mean 12-hours and "HH" might mean 24-hours.  All of these codes within their own software are subject to the whim of the programmer(s).

Comment: YYMMDD used to be unambiguous, up until about 13 years ago.

Comment: @supercat Depends on the domain.  On an ancestry site, it was always ambiguous (but the right value could be inferred, same as now)

Comment: @Izkata: Order ambiguity with YYMMDD would only be an issue if the earliest possible date was between January 1, 1900 and December 30, 1931.  If the earliest date could go further than that, specifying the century would be appropriate in any case, in which case YYYYMMDD would be essentially unambiguous given that YYYYDDMM is never used.  A date of the form 18xxyyzz, 19xxyyzz or 20xxyyzz, with yy being 12 or less, could only sensibly would be YYYYMMDD unless it represented a year prior to 1300.

Comment: @supercat I mentioned an ancestry site because the example I was thinking of was my great-grandfather being born in something like '97 (1897, not 1997).  So the 1999/2000/2001 rollover isn't the only time when 2-digit years were ambiguous, but whether it's a valid thing to be concerned about depends on the project's range - like an ancestry site

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps start with the year first? You'll initially throw someone off, but for a good reason. I have never seen a YYYY-DD-MM structure in the wild, only YYYY-MM-DD. It would seem to follow for users that this may not be how they are used to seeing the date, but it does make the expectations clear. You could also locate a key nearby for any date format (if this is say, a chart of events).

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is the format recommended by ISO 8601 and a XKCD 1179 (see other answers and comments). It's a possible solution, alright, but not the friendliest one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes we do; hence the [Public Service Announcement](http://xkcd.com/1179/) from xkcd on "... *the* correct way to write numeric dates".

Comment: When it comes to XKCD, I don't know if that's something that disturbs the general public, or maybe just the computer geeks, who can't stand the fact dates cannot be sorted alpha-numerically

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt an internationally recognizable format of dd-MON-yyyy to avoid confusion, For example, see: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/middleware/richclient/index.html?/webfolder/ux/middleware/richclient/guidelines5/commonFormats.html

However I think if the site, portal or app is US Domestic market or business only, then a US format is reasonable to assume.

Alternatively you could add a notation on the screen advising that the dates are shown in a US format (and give an example).

Ideally, the UX should allow the users to enter the date format using what they're comfortable with and do an on-fly conversion and then store the date in a format that can be rendered back as per user preference. UX considerations should also enable the user to select their format even within a locale convention.

For example, Sunday, January 28, 2011. A shortened format can also be used, e.g, Jan-28-11 or Jan-28-2011. As a general rule if the viewing audience is international or likely to be then avoiding an all number display format would be safer, though that seems to be outside your use case, so 01-28-2011 would be acceptable.

Comment: How is this an **international** standard? Try guessing what date this is: 28-Фев-2012.

Comment: @PashaS: The C language standard specifies that __DATE__ will expand to a macro with the compilation date using the first three characters of the English-language names of the months, so at least among programmers those three-letter sequences should be recognizable.  Incidentally, in some languages the month names are not unique in their first three characters (e.g. in French, the sixth and seventh months both start "Jui") but in English they are.  Month abbreviations are also distinct from weekday ones, unlike in French (the third month shares three letters with a weekday).

Comment: In addition, I may not know which month that refers to, but I know which element in the date it represents.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that Americans get confused with the date format is because they assume 01/02/2013 is 2 January 2013 in their format which is month day year, when in reality it is either 2 January 2013 (month day year) or 1 February 2013 (day month year). Year month day format is also confusing because the year is moved to the front. Americans are not used to talking like this. Example: “When is your birthday?” “Oh, my birthday is on the 2nd of April”. They will get it, but they are not used to it. They always talk like this. Example: “When is your birthday?” “Oh, it is on April 2nd”. When I see a numeric date, like 01/02/2013, I have to guess the format whether it is day month year or month day year. 
Overall use YYYY-MM-DD.
Written on 29 May 2019 at 14:24 UTC/GMT (2019-05-29T14:24:00 +0000 UTC)

Answer (score 0):

In **Iran** we have our calendar (Shamsi also known as Jalali Calendar) and we always use **YYYY/MM/DD**, we use this format for other calendars too (like Julian)

Other formats are really confusing for us, both European and American formats.

It doesn't make sense to me why some people use DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY as we tend to put larger units at the left side, like we do with decimal numbers.

When we use YYYY/MM/DD, it eases sorting and also calculating dates.

It seems the global standard systems should create a unique format to prevent confusing.

Comment: That is not what the question was about.