# Reasoning for American date format

Tags: dates

In America the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` but in Europe its written `dd/mm/yyyy`, what is the reasoning behind the American format, surely the most used piece of info in that string is `dd` so why put forward the month first ?

Comment: related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39905/do-american-users-also-confuse-the-day-and-the-month-in-dates-like-01-02-2013

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems it is just convention, as you can also see [at this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/date-format-in-uk-vs-us). The American format follows the phrase "November fifth", while the European one follows "the fifth of November".

When designing an interface you might find useful having fields with the name of the month, like `05 - Nov - 2013` or `Nov - 05 -2013` instead of using numbers and guidelines/explanations of the format you are using.

Comment: Yes. Just don't do what WordPress does -- when dating posts, it displays dates in the American order, but with the month number *and* the name. So July 4 is `07-Jul 4` This often confuses me, and I'm sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee: You'd have to dig into the format strings explanation, but you can get WordPress to display dates any way you like. Somewhere in the settings pages for the site admin.

Comment: @Marjan, the problem occurs when you are _entering_ dates, not displaying them; as far as I know, this is not configurable (except possibly for the language used for the month names).

Comment: @BennettMcElwee: Ah, I never do that... :-)

Answer (score 4):

While your question is valid, your underlying assumptions are not.

> surely the most used piece of info in that string is dd

Really? The question of what part of the date a user might be interested in, is really not all that easy to answer. It really depends on the application. Sometimes the day might be most relevant, but for other purposes the month, year or even century might be what the user is looking for.

**Iso format**

If you're looking for a really rational way to format dates, you should look at the ISO format yyyy mm dd (the spacing is optional, really). In this format, you put the most significant (as in: largest contribution to the total value) piece of information first, just like you do with every other number.  Benefits include that this format sorts naturally in chronological order.

Comment: [Obligatory relevant XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Sometimes the *night* might be most relevant. And if you are Jewish, the night belongs to the following day. That is: the day begins at sunset. This is the reason for phrases like "New Year's *Eve*" - the evening *before* New Year's Day. It comes from Genesis, which says things like "And there was evening, and there was morning: the first day." To me, this means the scholars got it backwards - Genesis is explicitly saying that the first day ended after the first night, as the next day dawned, which is common sense. But that was so long ago now. Who really cares?