# DD/MM/YY or DD/MM/YYYY?

Tags: dates, formatting, numbers

There have been discussions about the order of DD, MM, YYYY, but never really any discussion about why designers choose to use YYYY over YY (for instance, 01/01/2017 rather than 01/01/17).

Any idea why there is such a preference?

I can briefly think of some instances when including the entire YYYY is useful based on context, but assuming that the system I'm designing won't be dealing with century old objects, I wouldn't need the full YYYY. Am I right? Isn't it fine to just use YY then?

Comment: In the year 2099, *somebody* is going to curse your name...

Comment: Use neither.   https://xkcd.com/1179/     ...and a curse on your code if you ever use YYYY/DD/MM - that is an abomination.

Comment: I did not expect such a question just 17 years after Y2K.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601  "an unambiguous and well-defined method of representing dates and times":  YYYY-MM-DD .   For example, September 27, 2012 is represented as 2012-09-27. No slashes.  with time: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss ( or YYYY-MM-DDThhmmss for filenames), even including milliseconds if needed: .mmm .  The "T" separator really helps taking out every ambiguities, and is easy to parse as well. iso8601 is a good thing, and should be used EVERYWHERE ! (I have log-search scripts that needs to "guess" amongst 12 date formats :'( )

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56629/discussion-on-question-by-vincent-dd-mm-yy-or-dd-mm-yyyy).

Comment: If it says that someone was born on 01/01/13 then it is ambiguous... That person could be 4 or 114 years old. Specifying full year makes the date unambiguous while two digit years require context and exercising one's brain in order to interpret.

Comment: There is no situation when one should use anything but ISO 8601: `YYYY-MM-DD`. No exceptions.

Comment: _assuming that the system I'm designing won't be dealing with century old objects_ That's already a good reason to use YYYY, not to have to make such assumptions.

Comment: I think it makes a big difference whether you are talking about how to display it or how to store it and you haven't mentioned which one you are referring to.

Comment: Not century old. 17-year-old. If you have an object '99 and another '01, we all know you mean 1999 and 2001, but your computer will need special programming to know that, or it will order them incorrectly.

Comment: @yitzih et al. I believe it's an automatic and 100% safe assumption that here we are exclusively talking about displaying and not about storing. But it's true that it would have not hurt to make that explicit - just like the year in a date ;)

Comment: just because you display 07/04/17 doesn't mean the database is only storing 17. There's an advantage in saving space by not showing the redundant 20. Just so long as you record it as 2017.

Comment: If this is a desktop application you're developing, or some other context where you have access to a user's global date/locale preferences as configured by the host operating system, then *use those*. Otherwise, for a web app or something else, I'd say follow everyone else's advice and use the ISO format. (Every web site does not need yet another configuration page, and certainly not for something as trivial as a date format.)

Comment: Dude, Y2K already has the answer to your question!

Comment: "Those who cannot remember the past are condemned to repeat it" - George Santayana

Comment: Only use 31/12/2017. Why? Because I say so!

Comment: @sds Starting in the year 10000, the format YYYY-MM-DD will no longer do. That is one exception. Only one, but it will last a long time.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**There is no universally good answer to this question**, but there are definitely two pros of YYYY:

- by showing the two leading numbers you can easily tell e.g. 1911 from 2011,
- you know exactly where the year is in cases when the year is from the range XX01-XX12.

In other words:

```
Notation     Possible interpretations:
-----------  -------------------------
09/10/11     Four:
             September 10th 2011
             9th of October 2011
             2009, 10th of November
             2009, October 11th

09/10/2011   Two:
             September 10th 2011
             9th of October 2011
             
2009/10/11   Two as well:
             2009, 10th of November
             2009, October 11th
```

So, as you can see, by telling the User where the year is you limit the concern. Should the date be from a year which ends in a number higher than 31 (which is the highest number possible in the other fields), something interesting happens:

```
Notation     Possible interpretations:
-----------  -------------------------
09/10/33     Two:
             September 10th 2033
             9th of October 2033
```

**However**, the above interpretation requires the User to first analyse the contents of the string, so it increases the cognitive load significantly. The thinking would be:

*"Is 09 the year? Not sure. The middle one is not year. Oh, 33 is the year. So 09 must be the day or month."*

Of course this happens in a blink of an eye (Well, two of them. Well, three), but it is still a cognitive load and if Users need to deal with a lot of dates in this form, they may need to go through the same unwelcome process of searching for the year many times until they learn. And they should not have to learn.

And for these you do not need to bother of the contents, you can easily tell where the year is just looking at the obscured string:

- ▓▓-▓▓-▓▓▓▓
- ▓▓/▓▓/▓▓▓▓
- ▓▓▓▓/▓▓/▓▓
- ▓▓▓▓-▓▓-▓▓
- ▓▓▓▓-▓▓
- ▓▓-▓▓▓▓

#### The day vs month problem: gradual versus cultural approach

Now we get to the real culprit why the dates are so unclear: month versus day. Let us say, we have solved our problem with the year and still need to tell one from another here: ▓▓/▓▓/▓▓▓▓

```
Notation     Possible interpretations:
-----------  -------------------------
09/10/2033   Two:
             September 10th 2033
             9th of October 2033
```

For me, the gradual approach, where the time units consistently goes from lower to higher (so: DD/MM/YYYY) or the other way (YYYY/MM/DD) makes much more sense. Unfortunately, in a system that Users only approach from time to time it does not matter if you use this approach, because **they will not remember** that you have used it.

On the other hand, the MM/DD/YYYY format for the date is common in the US, Canada, Greenland, Philippines and several African countries ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)), as an abbreviation of the way the date is pronounced: "September 10th, 2017". However, as there is also another pronunciation allowed this brings only confusion.

To get out of this madness you may consider changing MM to the textual version of it (e.g. shortened: OCT/10/2017 or 09/SEP/2017), but in this case you fall into a problem of translation for international Users.

#### Professional usage

One situation when you do not need to bother about the notation is a situation when Users deal a lot with the date data, mostly in professional way. Two examples I can give you out of my head would be financial analysts (observing changes on the market) or photographers dealing with a lot of photos named using some convention they know by heart. If they know it by heart, this is not a concern.

#### "Now" context anchor

Another situation when the importance of what is year in the date becomes less important is when Users are more oriented on "now". Facebook is a good example.

#### Saving space

Saving space may be sometimes a really important factor for making decisions. Again, in dashboards containing a lot of data, the year may be either completely obsolete or may need to be truncated. But I believe these dashboards fall into the basket of professional usage most of the times, so no need to worry about them too much.

#### Combining into one text string and sorting

In some cases, you may face a situation when you need to combine the date into one big chunk of text. For example, the naming convention I use for photo files is `YYYYMMDD_HHmmSS.ext`, (e.g. `20170911_113426.RAF`) This, again, falls into the "pro" usage basket; however it also provides means for sorting by date without needing to worry that the date attribute of a file would change (e.g. because it was moved to a file system that does not support this kind of attribute, or edited in an app that would clear it). This usage scenario brings two conclusions:

- it is good to have a full year, because at least the photos from 2000 will be after those from 1999,
- it is good to use the gradual order, progressing from higher to lower unit.

#### Wrap-up:

- Do your Users know the system by heart? Do they use the date attribute on everyday basis? If so, do not bother about the recognition where the year is, but consider additional things like sortability or uniqueness (e.g. 1911 from 2011 when the date scope is wide.)
- Do your Users approach the date attribute only occasionally? If so, provide higher recognition for what is what in the date without high cognitive load from their side: expand the year to four digits, make it clear where the month is. Unless space is critical for you, in which case you need to prepare for trade-offs.

### EDIT:

As many comments below refer to ISO-8601 standard, I would like to explain why I have not added it in my original answer.

I believe that the word *"standard"* has a twofold meaning: a norm and a convention.

A ***a convention*** is a common approach to something that is used by a limited group of people. Regarding a specific topic like this one, there can be (and there usually are) various conventions, out of which one can contradict another (again: like in this case). And what is more, most of the conventions contradict the norm and the norm contradicts most of the conventions.

Conventions have their historical, linguistic, practical etc. roots. In case of date conventions, for example the MM/DD/YY comes from American way of saying the date as "November 5th, 2008" whereas somewhere else it can be different.

Now to the ***norm***.

A ***norm*** has a role to deny most of the conventions used so far, to replace most of them. It can be one of the conventions that has been selected as a norm, but most of the conventions need to be denied if just one has to stay. A norm usually is well thought out. The norm in this particular case makes a lot of sense, as every-next-unit in it is smaller than the previous one (and this allows easier comparison between dates, sorting by date as a text string etc.).

**There are definitely two ways** to go from here.

- One is to push the norm until it is used everywhere, in long term providing coherence in the standard used all over the world. Forcing people to use something different from what they have always used has got its drawbacks, and this way is - to some extent - against usability.
- The other option is to adapt to the local conventions people understand. Having derived from cultural, linguistic, practical reasons, the conventions **feel** locally more adequate. But at the same time, when people using some convention also meet the other ones while browsing the web may become confused when they see something different from what they got used to, and hailing this approach is also - to some extent - against usability.

This way, I still believe that there is no universally good answer to this question, and it may not appear any soon. What can be done for now is limiting some bits of confusion - like in case of the year being written as four, not two digits.

Comment: Relevant link: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: Why no mention of the ISO standard? YYYY-MM-DD. Surely the more people aware of the standard and the more people get used to seeing it, the better the standard and the lower the confusion.

Comment: https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html "ISO 8601 tackles this uncertainty by setting out an internationally agreed way to represent dates:  YYYY-MM-DD .   For example, September 27, 2012 is represented as 2012-09-27." . No slashes.   YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss ( or YYYY-MM-DDThhmmss for filenames), even including milliseconds if needed: .mmm .   Get used to the "T" separator: it really helps taking out every ambiguities, and is easy to parse as well. iso8601 is a good thing, and should be used EVERYWHERE :) (I have log-search scripts that needs to "guess" amongst 12 date formats :'( )

Comment: -1 for "There is no universally good answer to this question" ISO-8601 exists. It is *the* "universally good answer to this question". Period.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56630/discussion-on-answer-by-dominik-oslizlo-dd-mm-yy-or-dd-mm-yyyy).

Comment: While ISO 8601 is nice to the programmers, it's not nice to the users. In reality, date should be formatted according to user language settings. Yes, year should never shortened and ideally the month should be text, not a number. That's why we have "Unicode Technical Standard #35".

Comment: @Sulthan "date should be formatted according to user language settings".  The problem with this is that, more often than not, *the user doesn't know if the date has been formatted according to their language settings*.  If a British person visits an American website and sees `01/10/17`, how do they know which format is being used?  Of course you can solve that with `01 Oct 17` but then you have added a new internationalization problem.  I agree with using the ISO format.  The unfamiliarity problem is smaller than other problems, and the more it is used, the more this problem goes away.

Comment: @dan1111 - I agree to some extent, but to some I do not. First, standard is a good thing when it is commonly used. ISO-8601 is not. Using locally common notation makes date unfamiliar for those who come from somewhere else. Using text for month triggers linguistic problem – I would know March, but not მარტი, which is in Georgian. This is why I still believe there is no universally good notation, even though there is a standardised one. Should this standard be commonly used, yes, this would be the correct answer.

Comment: I agree that there is no *perfect* solution.  But I would lean much more toward that ISO standard as the best of the imperfect solutions.

Comment: One additional point about the sorting topic: Beginning with (I believe it was) Windows Vista, Microsoft changed the operating system's alphanumeric sorting algorithm with respect to filenames, from a simple dictionary-style sort to a system that sorts any sequence of consecutive digits as a single number unit within the filename, such that the hex strings properly sorted as 777, 98F, 990, 99A, 9A0 are instead sorted as **9**A0, **98**F, **99**A, **777**, **990**, and that any date in the format MM-DD-YYYY will sort all January items together regardless of year. (And DD-MM-YYYY is even worse!)

Comment: @Shane Not according to every business I have ever worked for in the last 20 years in the US. They all have demand MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: As an American who has lived in and done business with commonwealth countries, please please ensure your format isn't simply _implied_ by whatever region your office happens to be in. Be explicit. Personally I write "6 April 2017", or "April 6, 2017". Zero confusion. Your users **do not** bring the same assumptions you do.

Comment: You write "2009/10/11   Two as well:" There is not and never will be a YYYY/DD/MM date code, this is why your argument while long is wasted.  The ISO-8601 YYYY-MM-DD option is the solution that you hide from by inventing a nonexistent conflict to try and obscure the obvious bias in favour of the standard.

Comment: @DominikOslizlo _standard is a good thing when it is commonly used._ I disagree, a standard is a good thing when there is the need for one. Then if for any reason it doesn't get used by the majority (in this case, mostly due to laziness or resistance to change), it's still good that it's there, because in that way it still has the chance of becoming commonly used; once enough people get fed up with the guessing and switch to the standard, the problem is solved forever and for everybody. The problem of not knowing what format that date is is caused by knowing that it might be one of several.

Answer (score 64):

As a rule, it's *never* OK to use a 2-digit year.  If you can prove that using a 4-digit year will cause thousands of babies and cute fluffy bunnies to die horribly, that could be an exception to the rule, but probably not.

I have seen hundreds of costly process failures simply because a programmer thought it was perfectly OK to use a 2-digit year or a local date idiom *this* time.

But I have never once seen a program or process fail due to the choice of [YYYY-MM-DD ISO 8601 Standard Date Formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  It's *always* the right choice.  Take this advice to heart, and you'll never regret it.

The YYYY-MM-DD standard form is equally comprehensible to people from any country, of any age - even ones that were born in countries where the traditional format is something objectively braindead, like MM/DD/YY or DD/YY-MM.  It also sorts correctly without reformatting, a bonus feature!

Comment: +10,000 if I could.  This is a solved problem and there need be no more discussion or wishy-washiness.

Comment: Standard published almost 20 years ago that settles this issue. We are still arguing over it.... [Mandatory xkcd link](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: That it sorts correctly without formatting isn't so much a bonus feature as inherent in the choice of putting the most-significant units on the left.  One might even say it's the reason for that choice.  It's certainly my primary reason for pushing ISO-8601 date formats whenever I can.  That it's literally an international standard gives me the high ground in any conflict that might emerge.

Comment: "objectively braindead" is kinda unnecessary

Comment: "Objectively braindead" is not only unnecessary, but also insulting and incorrect. MM/DD/YY is common because it is how dates are spoken where that format is used. September 7th, 99 = 09/07/99. It's objective and correct, just with a different goal.

Comment: @thunderblaster If this was true stackexchange should have failed long ago - we all use it everyday -  it uses YY for all previous years. Want to verify it again?

Comment: "I have never once seen a program or process fail due to the choice of YYYY-MM-DD ISO 8601 Standard Date Formatting." +1

Comment: " If you can prove that using a 4-digit year will cause thousands of babies and cute fluffy bunnies to die horribly" - then I'd use a 5-digit year. Y10K is coming fast anyways.

Comment: @DCShannon "MM/DD/YY is common because it is how dates are spoken where that format is used." I have heard "on the 7th of September 1999" spoken in those countries, so even that argument does not hold.

Comment: @Diego using an ambiguous format for dates normally does not make businesses _fail_. That doesn't mean it's a good format.

Comment: @DCShannon If there is one thing that MM/DD/YY is not is _objective_. It's based solely on the habit of a group of countries, basically [only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) North America, Greenland, Kenya, Nigeria, Philippines and a few micro-countries. It has no underlying objective logic. It's not from smallest to greatest or viceversa (while all the formats that have MM in the middle are) and it's not sortable. One might love it or not and it might even have a lot of qualities that other formats don't have, but from what do you infer its quality of being _objective_?

Comment: @SantiBailors The logic is that it is spoken that way. There need not be any more logic. I think it's fine to display that to a NA user, but capture/storage is another thing. In all apps I've written, we use MM/DD/YYYY, but the values are always stored in the DB as YYYYMMDD and the UI just converts to/from as needed. Humans can parse MM/DD/YY just fine based on context. Computers... not so much.

Comment: @ChrisSchneider _Humans can parse MM/DD/YY just fine based on context._ I have no idea how you can say that. Not counting of course my personal experience (which by the way is the same of all the other non-North-Americans/Greenlanders etc. with whom I ever discussed this) of having to guess the meaning of those potentially American dates every time the day is <= 12, you have several comments right in this page describing difficulties in doing exactly that. Unless by _"based on context"_ you mean "based on knowing in which format those dates are".

Comment: Let me rephrase... "_Americans_ can parse MM/DD/YY just fine based on context." If your UI is for different countries, you should have a hint, anyway.

Comment: Does any software actually display an ISO 8601 date on the user interface? I would like to see one.

Comment: While it's certainly true that the *programmer* should use the ISO format for the logic, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's the best format to use in a UX context. When viewing their Amazon purchase history, most consumers would prefer to see their regional date format on the page over an ISO-formatted date, even though the database itself likely *stores* the dates in ISO format.

Comment: @Diego but it uses a `'` so we know it's a year.

Comment: @DanHenderson _When viewing their Amazon purchase history, most consumers would prefer to see their regional date format on the page over an ISO-formatted date_ I disagree; when using software most consumers would prefer to see the same date format everywhere, even if it's not the local one, because they want to be sure and not have to wonder, and they know that they don't know what format the non-local developers / designers used. Nowadays there is no longer such a thing as a UI for certain countries; except for very few, marginal, irrelevant cases, a UI is for the whole world.

Comment: @Salman A, every computer and every application in my (USA) workplace uses ISO 8601 formatted dates at all times.  We've forced it on thousands of windows desktop clocks with group policy.  Not one person has ever complained about it or been unable to understand it.

Answer (score 17):

Take this example: **01/02/07**.

At first look, it could be anything. Now, let's make it YYYY: **01/02/2007**.

Quite a bit of difference, right? This is one of the main reasons for the YYYY format. Very few datapoints are in *2-digit / 2-digit / 4-digit* format, and this helps avoid a bit of confusion.

Comment: This is an interesting example. Have never thought about it, it does seem clearer with the full YYYY. 

Regarding MM/DD and DD/MM, would you think that it is unavoidable to have some confusion over it? I'm not that particularly worried about this because my data is presented as a table format. It is easy to spot DD which exceeds 12. 

On a side note, while taking more space, would you think that 12 Jun 2017 works best?

Comment: @Vincent The confusiobn about MM and DD is avoidable only if you place full year first, like YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: You picked one of the few examples where it does not matter; ignoring the uncertainty about the century, this is always Nov 11 2011, no matter how it is paresed ;)

Comment: @Yogu: The point of this answer is not that the YYYY notation helps readers to disambiguate the *date*. This answer shows that the YYYY notation helps readers to realize quickly that they are dealing with *dates* in the first place.

Comment: this! Just a few days ago I read a article somewhere dated from (something like) 11/05/15. I wonder when it was written... :-) 2011? 2015? May? November?...

Comment: @Vincent Yup, I use formats like "Sep 5, 2017" or "5 Sep, 2017" as much as possible, to completely eliminate doubt. It's also natural language, so it's easier to read as well.

Comment: "01/02/07... could be anything." No it couldn't. It's clearly a date and it's clearly either 01-Feb-2007 or 02-Jan-2007 (unless there's some context that implies some other century). 01/02/2007 is also clearly a date and also clearly means either 01-Feb-2007 or 02-Jan-2007. There's essentially no difference between the two in terms of recognizing them as dates and in terms of parsability.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I make software for warehouses, and I have at least six clients who use the 2-digit / 2-digit / 2-digit nomenclature for indexing their inventory. Because we ran into the exact same problem, we switched to the DD-Mon-YY format— 04 Oct 17.

This is simply one example, I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: @SujanSundareswaran And you'd have had exactly the same problem if they'd used 2/2/4.

Answer (score 10):

When you are not dealing with century old events - it will make perfect sense to use YY instead of YYYY.

Even Stackexchange follows the same pattern:

## "asked Jan 6 '09"

[image]

---

[MM/DD or DD/MM does change continent wise](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39905/do-american-users-also-confuse-the-day-and-the-month-in-dates-like-01-02-2013), but the YY or YYYY remains the same for entire world (At least in countries that use English as official language).

[**ISO 2014**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), though superseded, is the standard that originally introduced the all-numeric date notation in most-to-least-significant order **[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]**. The ISO week numbering system was introduced in ISO 2015, and the identification of days by ordinal dates was originally defined in ISO 2711.

## Truncated representations

> ISO 8601:2000 allowed truncation (by agreement), where leading
>   components of a date or time are omitted. Notably, this allowed
>   two-digit years to be used and the ambiguous formats **YY-MM-DD and
>   YYMMDD**. This provision was removed in ISO 8601:2004.

---

## From MS Window 10:

The YY options are completely valid

[image]

Comment: +1 For Iso Format. Come on ! Just use 2011-10-09, the standard is set since 1988 ! https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas They also had *YY-MM-DD and YYMMDD but this provision was removed in ISO 8601:2004.*

Comment: If I'm not dealing with century old events, but say, two decades of yearly reports, that I want to process in order, I order by date and get: 01, 02,... 16, 17, 97, 98, 99   Well, there is an aparent jump, and it isn't in date order...  Use the full year notation, and use the ISO standard where possible

Comment: @Baldrickk This is actually a great point IMO and I'm surprised no one else talked about it really.

Comment: _"the YY or YYYY remains the same for entire world"_ It certainly doesn't. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Copyright expiry under international treaties is set at the end of the Gregorian calendar year, disregarding the Hijri calendar. So yes, there exists a context in which YYYY remains the same for practically the entire world.

Comment: @DamianYerrick: Sure there are select circumstances, but it's not a general fact

Comment: `When you are not dealing with century old events - it will make perfect sense to use YY instead of YYYY. ` This is not corect, because using just to digits makes it useless to search for years. Searching for 2017 versus searching for 17 gives two completely different results, the first wil typically result in useful data, the second one will typically give usesless results.

Comment: wait... what is MMM?!?!

Comment: @netrox it's Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.

Comment: @hlovdal Have you seen a year old posts on UX.SE.. did you notice they use YY?

Comment: @Dipak [Yes I have indeed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14889/133217).

Answer (score 10):

Taking into account that this question was asked in the UX section of stackexchange, I would assume that the answer should focus on the user's expectations.

I have personally been working in a large Y2K project, and I would expect that software developers have learned their lesson from such projects. However, there still seems to be a certain disagreement about what that lesson is. It is *not* that 2-digit years are always evil.

It is a historic misconception that the primary reason for storing year values in 2 digits was to save storage memory. The truth is that *the users wanted 2-digit years* in their interface mainly because they did not want to enter unnecessary data. *The developers' fault was not to differentiate* between the user interface data and the stored data. It would have been perfectly okay to use 2-digit years in the user interface, as long as they were stored in 4 digits. If done so, any ambiguity would have been detected instantly instead of years later.

As a consequence, when it comes to UX, I would answer that **it is perfectly acceptable to use 2-digit years in the user interface, as long as**

- it is not ambiguous in the given context
- it is always stored as a 4-digit value

To illustrate 'given context':

- a flight date on a booking site works well with a 2-digits year, because the user will never be able to book a flight date that is over 100 years in the future
- a birthday date will hardly ever work well with a 2-digit-year, because at least some people get older than 100 years

Answer (score 9):

I thought the argument about yyyy rather than yy had been dealt with in the run-up to y2k? There are almost certainly people reading this who will be alive to see 2099 turn to 2100, and there are almost certainly coders who have failed to learn the lesson whose code will go horribly pear-shaped come 2100 (when it will still be in use by somebody, somewhere).

Also, people are living to beyond their 100th birthday in ever-increasing numbers. Assuming that a user-entered date of birth is always less than a hundred years ago is likely to be a very poor assumption in the near future. I've already read of letters addressed to the parents of 104-year-old pensioners concerning the selection of their first school -- legal threats concerning the non-attendance of these pensioners at primary school are certain to follow soon!

Comment: Internal storage representation and I/O representation are separate issues.  An advantage of YYYY-MM-DD is that it avoids month/day ambiguity, but if users will be entering many dates, requiring that the year be typed for each of them doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: Ironically, your piece of text "dd Mon yyyy" is ambiguous because I first interpreted "Mon" as "Monday", not "Month"

Comment: I'm rather afraid that some of my old code might break sometime in 2036 ...

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD doesn't baffle anyone. It has a 100% success rate in decoding. The worst that can be said is that it's unfamiliar to the general public, but it's intuitive. DD-MM-YYYY is not intuitive, and MM-DD-YYYY is even counter-intuitive.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, you know, I'm a bit surprised to have had to scroll this far down for someone to mention this - Y2K was basically a scam for consultants to make quick money - 32-bit UNIX timestamps are *everywhere*. Hopefully won't be in 2 decades, but still.

Comment: "Y2K was basically a scam for consultants to make quick money" No, Y2K was an actual problem that didn't cause many issues because we fixed it in time.

Comment: It is only ambiguous for 11 out of the first 12 days of every month!

Comment: "There are almost certainly people reading this who will be alive to see 2099 turn to 2100" . You have more optimism about homo sapiens than I do. I'll grant that it is likely -- but "almost certainly"?

Answer (score 4):

Using YYYY over YY ensures it is immediately obvious which of the three fields represents the year. This resolves some ambiguity, not just between different centuries, but also between date formats. However, DD/MM/YYYY is rarely an acceptable representation.

For display purposes, you may want to use a long format, e.g.: 'Tuesday 4 April 2017'. It is clear and unambiguous, but takes up a large and variable amount of space and may require translation into other languages.

For numerical representations, always use YYYY-MM-DD ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), which is guaranteed to be unambiguous, is an ISO standard, is easy to parse by both computers and humans (even those accustomed to other formats), requires no localisation and can be ordered chronologically by lexical sorting.

Answer (score 4):

Advantages of YY:

- Saves 2 letters of space
- Saves 0.2 seconds of time when typing the date.

Disadvantages of YY

- Requires you to use different date formats in the same product (you must use YYYY in some cases, at some point)
- Adds ambiguity (which century?)
- Adds ambiguity (which one is the year and which one the month?)
- Adds ambiguity (which one is the year and which one the day?)
- Takes 0.2 seconds longer to read (because of ambiguity)
- Increases risk of user error (worse input verification, and because of ambiguity)
- Increases risk of programming errors (usually involving sorting)

You should weigh advantages and disadvantages against each other based on your use case - saving these 2 letters is suddenly important if the next best alternative is scrolling on a LED display. Saving .2 seconds of typing can be quite useful in a workflow that needs a user to enter 1'000 dates a day. But in pretty much all other cases the balance tilts the other way.

Comment: It's a good way to look at it, but I suggest doing the PRO and CON of YYYY too. The disadvantages of YY are not necessarily a 1:1 match with the advantages of YYYY.

Answer (score 3):

The Y2K changeover created lots of work, which was good from a monetary view - but it was really *boring* work.
I wont live to see 2100, but please don't make life boring for our heirs...

(Not clear enough? From ~1985 to 1999 we all spend many hours of work upgrading systems where developers who lacked foresight had used 2-digit dates. Please don't repeat that error.)

Comment: Love me some fun anecdotes in answers!  Y2K was fun indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Most of the people uses DD/MM/YYYY format.
Based on region/country format is varying. [Date format by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't know they actually kept a record of which format each country uses frequently. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: +1 for such an interesting and useful link.  But remember the majority is not guaranteed right or best.

Comment: https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html "ISO 8601 tackles this uncertainty by setting out an internationally agreed way to represent dates:  YYYY-MM-DD .   For example, September 27, 2012 is represented as 2012-09-27." . No slashes.  with time: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss ( or YYYY-MM-DDThhmmss for filenames), even including milliseconds if needed: .mmm .  The "T" separator really helps taking out every ambiguities, and is easy to parse as well. iso8601 is a good thing, and should be used EVERYWHERE :) (I have log-search scripts that needs to "guess" amongst 12 date formats :'( )

Comment: @Criggie it's sensible to target your usage to the usage of the majority of your users.

Comment: With "most", you refer to the order (DMY), but not the separator, right? If you say most use "DD/MM/YYYY", it suggests that most would use the slash to separate, but the linked page doesn’t seem to claim this.

Comment: @OlivierDulac One should match interfaces to the users. If you're making something that will be used by international users, without being localized, then yeah, use the ISO standard. That doesn't mean it's appropriate everywhere all the time. Log scripts aren't users, and that has nothing to do with user interface design.

Comment: -1 a relevant fact and useful link but not a satisfactory answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

For timestamps, in file or directory names I always use `YYYYmmdd` that way normal lexical sorting (e.g. `ls -l command`) always lists stuff in the correct sequence.  Neither `mmddYYYY` nor `ddmmYYYY` has that property.

In handwritten notes, I sometimes use just `YYmmdd` for convenience and when I won't be confusing the century.

Of course in the year 9999 this notation will once again cause much angst.

Comment: A proposal to extent ISO-8601 solves this:

For any five-digit year, prefix with "A", six-digit with "B", etc:
`99991231,
A100000101,
...
A999991231,
B1000000101,
...
B999999-12-31`

this allows for 30-digit years that will still sort correctly.  But I also have some application logs in the *YYMMDD.log format, which doesn't bother me awfully much, as the logs aren't retained long enough to be a problem.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question about whether it should be 2 or 4 digits long, just that you do it as YY for convenience. Can you elaborate and explain whether YY or YYYY is more beneficial, and why?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve.  In some cases (perhaps more than you think) users may need to see a 4-digit year, while in others a two-digit year is adequate. It's not just century-old events that you have to consider, and it depends how you expect your users to input dates. Here are some examples:

- **Date of birth:** 1999 comes before 2000, but 99 would sort after 00, so
  for a DOB in something like a drop-down, a 4-digit year makes sense
  (displaying 2 digits but sorting by 4 is doable, but can be confusing
  to the user).
- **Calendar app:**  Google calendar's interface isn't ideal for this, but
  I can add events before the POSIX epoch -- so if I had diaries from
  the 60s I could digitise them into google (that would be a bad idea,
  besides I wan't born then).  Alternatively I could probably use it to
  plan out a novel set in the 23rd century.  *If you're building
  something general-purpose, your users will come up with more uses for
  it than you ever could*.

A bit of opinion: this clarity/flexibility beats saving space.

On the other hand it's possible to work in a much more restricted time-frame. If you're selling theatre tickets, and events can only take place within the next year or so, users only need to see a two-digit year.  Even past orders would make complete sense with only YY in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Before I write my view, must say it was great answer by @Dominik Oslizlo!

Ok, for the year format, I think it totally depends on the following:

- **Audience** (Their geographical region) - Users in Asian countries prefer saying the date first and then specify the month. It's opposite for the North America or western countries. For example, 9/11 is the American way of telling date whereas in India it's 26/11. Now, this is an interesting example as both the dates are associated with terrorist attacks. 9/11(11th Sept), the world knows about it and 26/11 (26th Nov) for the Mumbai attacks. The way it is referred is noticable. It reflects the culture.

So already there are chances of mixing up the date and month, year is better mentioned full (YYYY)

- **Purpose** (If the purpose to ask date and year to establish an event happened recently or is it a date of birth) Imagine a case of birthdays. Is there any way one can ascertain that user was born in 19yy or 20yy if it's mentioned only yy format.

**Conclusion:**

To avoid ambiguity, follow the DDMMYYYY format. It supports the way we refer the year in our daily lives. The tendency is to say 20 17 or 2k17 or whatever, but its complete YYYY format.

So, support the way users think. Hence YYYY would always be clear!

Comment: Can you explain how the DDMMYYYY format follows alphabetical order?

Comment: @Nayuki "D" < "M" < "Y"

Comment: You say that, Americans and westerners in general prefer to put the month name before the day. This is not true. Americans do generally say, e.g., "April 5th", which matches the way they write dates in numbers. British English seems equally happy with "the 5th of April" and "April 5th"; French and German (as far as I'm aware) only say the equivalent of "5th April" and (though I admit this is getting sketchy) using Google to translate "April 5th" into just about any European langauge seems to give the equivalent of "5 April".

Comment: I cannot think of a more wrong / pointless criterion than following the alphabetical order of D, M, Y. I agree about  the pros of DDMMYYYY  that you mentioned but I would definitely avoid any reference to the alphabetical order.

Comment: Yup agreed! Alphabetical order basis doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, when it comes to dates, I always use the 3 digit representation for the month, just because Americans...

As many have pointed out 09/10/11 could be 9th Oct or 10th Sep, whereas if you have 09/Oct/11, all users know what you are looking for.

Either that, or have some (obvious) way for the user to know what the fields are (e.g. putting "in (dd/mm/yy)" format in the question or using placeholder text in the inputs)

When it comes to years, using yy is much easier for users, but it depends what you are using it for. If it is for a medical form, it isn't impossible to have someone who was born in the 1920's who would fill out the form. So in a few years you may find your form very confusing when you have an apparent baby filling out a form requiring a hip replacement.

Comment: 11th Oct of 2009?

Comment: But using words means you have internationalization problems.

Comment: It solves the problem for "all users" *who speak English*.

Comment: @dan1111 I'd make the assumption that the site would translate based on the user's language (or by allowing the user to change the site's language) - if aiming for international audiences. E.g. default may be 09/Feb/11, but in French see 09/Fev/11

Comment: Most of this answer is referring to date format. Only the last paragraph actually answers the question that was asked - should year be 2 or 4 digits.

Answer (score -1):

#### Distinguish between display for personal use and form for interchange of data between users.

**1. In the device:** Keep user in control. Respect local settings of date format. Whether the user has system-wide YYYY or YY, respect it.

- Display all dates according to local settings in the machine.
- Expect entry of all dates according to local settings in the machine *PLUS* additionally allow ISO format for date entry (YYYY-MM-DD).

**2. Context of user account:** if user can log into a platform (e.g. website), take format settings from his profile. As a default, you can set ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD) or get the format based on user's country (see [Veeresh's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/106625/45260)). Initially use ISO format when country is unknown. Once you have determined the format, handle date display and date entry as described in point 1 above. So YYYY or YY comes from the setting.

**3. Global use:** if data are targetted to be handed over to other users (e.g. reports in text form), always use YYYY, especially ISO date form YYYY-MM-DD. This will leave no one in doubts.

Comment: The question is not about date format. It is about whether the year should be 2, or 4 digits long.

Comment: @JonW – thank you for pointing to that. I modified the answer accordingly to make its point more clear. The YYYY vs. YY is generally out of debate on systems where system-wide format settings already exist. (Ignoring them and introducing independent display form is a bad practice.) Where this is not settable, YYYY should be preferred (as part of YYYY-MM-DD, not other order) to avoid any doubts.