# dd/mm/yyyy date format: Is this weird / unnatural for Americans?

Tags: dates, datetimepicker

The month first format. Do you, as an American, find this unnatural?

And: If you were in a hurry, would you start typing the month first (as this is most natural for you)?

Edit: This question differs from [this one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39905/do-american-users-also-confuse-the-day-and-the-month-in-dates-like-01-02-2013) because I'm asking how likely you would enter mm-dd-yyy in a dd-mm-yyyy input if you were in a hurry (even if it was labelled). The other question is about appearance rather than entry. A nuance, yes, but this is UX and it is not a nuance in this context.

Comment: I'm not an American, and I'd be confused, too. It's ambiguous and needs explanation and often a moment of thinking. https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: I am an American, and yes, it is weird.  Just use an ISO date, please.

Comment: @jamesdlin 'normal' people find the ISO date format weird as well. just use local conventions.

Comment: @Midas Any date format is going to be weird to some group of people.  You might as well use the ISO date format which is weird *and unambiguous*.

Comment: Re: Duplicate marking, please undo this. This question is different to that one.

Comment: Re: ISO date. Read the url bar: **UX**. For the normal user (yes, this is unfortunate) ISO dates are weird. think grandpa / grandma.

Comment: It's not a question that can be correctly answered though. Who is this singular American 'you' that can answer this?

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for the response. Please, Americans, weigh in on this.

Comment: @JonW: This cannot be answered in toto obviously. I cannot get a 95 confidence interval from a few respondents on SE. Obviously. I just want a feeling from a few Americans. This is fundamental so my reasoning is that answers from a few will be enough information. Are you American? If so, weigh in.

Comment: I agree that it is not a duplicate, as the other question is essentially asking if 01/01/2020 can be confusing without the MM/DD labels. This question is asking more about are the labels themselves helpful enough indicators to avoid confusion. However, as the question stands I won't vote to reopen as I find "Do you, as an American, find this unnatural?" only to lead to purely opinion based/debating answers. I would recommend rephrasing it such as "How to label date inputs in an unambigous way to American users" or something. As an aside, I'm american and I do tend to find it confusing.

Comment: This isn't a site for conducting polls though. It's for stating a specific problem and finding the solution to it. That's why you can only accept one answer - the answer that best solves your problem. What you're asking for is dozens / hundreds of individual answers each just saying 'Yes' or 'No'. That's not what this site is about. Please see the [TOUR] page for more info.

Comment: @ DasBeasto The problem with SE. 100 moderators jumping down your throat when x parameter does not match y on the TOS. This question would be valuable, regardless of the fine print, on this site. An answer like: "I just asked three co-workers around me and they all said it was weird" would get a tick.

Comment: *I asked three co-workers aroudn me and they all said it was amazing*. J/k, the point is that you'll need to run the tests yourself, right now you're doing a survey. Or willing to accept any answer, no matter if right or wrong (3 people , 5 people or 10 people are not enough). Thus, this is an interesting question, but unless someone finds a study, it has no answer and it won't  help anyone,

Comment: Well, since this *is* `ux.stackexchange.com`, then you could have your users use a date-picker control or have separately labeled year, month, and day inputs.